# I've this problem to be solved regarding struct and function pointers which returns string

Tags: c

I need a small code which would:

A struct containing:
1. a 2 by 3 array of real numbers, and
2. a pointer to a function that takes a integer number and returns a
string.

```
    struct realnumbers;
{


     int array = [2][3] ;
 }
    int string(struct realnumbers *ptr);
```

Comment: struct realnumbers;
{
    int array = [2][3] ;
};
int string(struct realnumbers *ptr);

Comment: You need to provide what you already have. SO is not a service to write programs for you.

Comment: I got this. But i don't think it returns string

Comment: you can google the syntax for each

Comment: @Ali Ashar OK, and what did you try putting in the function? Add it to the question itself.

Comment: Hallo! You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @NellieDanielyan I get that but how do I return a string in C language?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @FireLancer Done

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's right. I get that but can you kindly help me with it. I'm stuck with in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not that far from your target:

```
struct my_struct {
    float array[2][3];
    char* (*function)(int);
};
```

"Real numbers" and "strings" can be represented in C in many ways, but `float` and `char*` are probably the most popular options. Two dimensional array also can be represented in several ways, but your approach is okay.

Comment: Thanks bud. This seems very fine. Appreciate your help